# sending bulk Whatsapp messages Android

Tags: php, android, messaging, whatsapp, viber

I am working on an android application and i want to integrate whats-app or viper messaging in order to be able to send the same messages to all my contacts... i have searched too much and i knew that there is no official API and there are some unofficial trials

https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI

,but without documentation so i didn't understand how to deal with them....

so i would like to know if there is a way to deal with these apps programmatically  ??

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

No there is no way to interact with these apps until the device is rooted , If you have a rooted device you can manipulate the messages from SQLLite and can fiddle with that , but I dont think what you are trying to do is possible without banning your registered Viber or whatsapp number. The WHatsAPI in github is actually working but dont send more then 5 messages at a time , else your number will be banned for life.